# Can a minor listen to phone navigation instructions while driving in Oregon?

Tags: driving, minor, oregon

If a minor set up (for example) Google Maps voice navigation while parked, then started driving (listening to the phone's instructions), then parked at the destination and turned the navigation off, would he be breaking any laws? Does "using" a device require interacting with it while driving? If I'm reading the relevant law ([ORS 811.507](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_811.507)) correctly, if merely listening to a device that was already configured constituted using it, an adult could only listen to a radio if it could be controlled by voice.

Comment: Which law are you looking at?

Comment: ORS 811.507 https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_811.507

Comment: Do you think it matters whether the person is a minor?

Comment: Yes. "It is an affirmative defense to a prosecution of a person under this section that the person: ... Was 18 years of age or older and was using a hands-free accessory;"

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/21150/legality-of-using-a-phone-for-gps-in-oregon?rq=1

Comment: @MichaelHall, that question is focused on the "GPS" aspect of the situation; this is focused on the "minor" part of the situation.

Comment: @Someone: That is really interesting. So it seems that they trust people above 18 to drive with a hands free handset safely, but not 16 year olds. I wonder if there are other things that a 16 year old with a driving license cannot do, and an 18 year old can.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes. An 18 year old with an amateur radio license may talk on the radio while driving (without needing a handsfree accessory), but a 16 year old may not (even with a handsfree accessory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening to navigation instructions coming from a phone would meet the definition of:

> (1)(e) “**Using** a mobile electronic device” includes but is not limited to using a mobile electronic device for text messaging, voice communication, entertainment, **navigation**, accessing the Internet or producing electronic mail.

The next section goes on to say that:

> (2) **A person commits the offense** of driving a motor vehicle while using a mobile electronic device if the person, while driving a motor vehicle on a highway or premises open to the public:

> (b) Uses a mobile electronic device for **any purpose**.

Later in section (4) it states "It is an **affirmative defense** to a prosecution of a person under this section that the person:"

> (b) Was **18 years of age or older** and was using a hands-free accessory;

Since your minor in question was using a portable electronic device for navigation, and due to their age cannot exercise the "hands-free" defense, it is logical to conclude that your scenario would be a violation of this statute.

Silly as it might seem, this apparently wouldn't preclude them from interacting with a permanently installed navigation unit while driving unless it was observed to be causing a distraction since (1)(d)(A) states:

> “Mobile electronic device” means an electronic device that is **not permanently installed** in a motor vehicle.

Comment: If I buy an phone and permanently mount it in the vehicle (so it could be considered an aftermarket modification instead of a separate device), would it be legal to use it for navigation?

Comment: @Someone, see my last addition at the bottom...

Comment: Okay, thank you. What is considered permanently installed?

Comment: @Someone, I can only interpret what is in the law you referenced.  I would say a suction cup mount on the windshield is not.  Anything you could pop the phone out of and put it in your pocket conveniently is not.  Buy a dedicated nav system, or car stereo with multi-function nav screen and you ought to be good to go.  That said, I believe that most of these laws are secondary offenses, meaning a cop would need another reason to pull you over, and would have to know that your minor had been using the device for navigation.

Comment: I get the intent to keep teens from texting while driving, but would you rather they listen and follow directions on a dashboard phone, or use a paper map?!

Comment: Yeah, the law as it's written doesn't seem completely logical. So if I fastened the phone to the car in a way that prevented me from detaching it while driving, it would likely be okay?

Comment: @MichaelHall, I'd rather have them use a paper map.  Back in the days when paper maps were the common means of navigation, the common method of using them was to figure out the route in advance and drive it from memory.

Comment: I couldn't find a definition for "permanently installed" in the law, but I might not have been looking in the right place.

Comment: Well, nothing is really permanent.  Easy enough to change your car stereo for example.  (even engines can be replaced)  I say just use your best judgement.  They can't legislate common sense, nor do we want them to...